# function call html vs react

Tags: html, reactjs

Could someone help me in understanding the difference between function calls made in React and Normal HTML/JS?

```
Normal HTML/Javascript : <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
React : <button onclick={this.myFunction}>Click me</button>
```

In both cases, the DOM will get loaded/rendered so to avoid the function call being made during load/render we are passing reference in React, but why the function is being called directly in HTML?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Normal HTML doesn't have any method call. You're talking about Javascript and since React is Javascript as well... share your source code.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you wondering why the React function call is inside braces? You might look at the rendered HTML to see the outcome of that syntax.

Comment: The important thing to understand: JSX is not HTML, it's a superset of JavaScript, so in the end, React will never render `onclick` in the DOM, it's entirely managed with the browser API (`addEventListener`, etc).

Comment: @EmileBergeron, so in case of HTML/JS while the page is loading the onClick will get invoked automatically?

Comment: In HTML, the `onclick` attribute value is a string, it's not JavaScript that's interpreted on load.